# How to inject mock in parent class with Mockito?

Tags: unit-testing, mockito

I'm using mockito to mock my services..

How can I inject mocks in parent class?

Sample:

```
public abstract class Parent(){

    @Mock
    Message message;

}

public class MyTest() extends Parent{

    @InjectMocks
    MyService myService //MyService has an instance of Message

    //When I put @Mock Message here it works
}
```

When I run my tests the message in `Parent` stay `null`

Comment: mocks can be injected via constructor. if doing DI then architecture the classes to get dependencies via constructor injection

Comment: Which mockito version are you using?

Comment: The version I'm using is: 1.10.19

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ways to solve this:

1) You need to use `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` in the `@Before` method in your parent class.

The following works for me:

```
public abstract class Parent {
    @Mock
    Message message;

    @Before
    public void initMocks() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
}

public class MyTest extends Parent {
    @InjectMocks
    MyService myService = new MyService(); //MyService has an instance of Message
    ...
}
```

2) If want to use the `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` above the class definition, then this must be done in the Parent class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class Parent {
...
```

Note that declaring the `@Mock` in both the `Parent` and `MyTest` class will cause the injected object to be null. So you will have to pick where you want to declare this.